# Data Structure Tree of Tree's

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

In Java can you have a Tree data structure where each node is a tree itself? Would the tree of tree's then be organized by the head node of the different tree's?

Comment: A tree *is* a data structure where each node is a tree itself.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is can each node in a tree store a separate tree?

Comment: Each node would be the root for the subtree that branches from that node.

Comment: A node can store any object. There is no limitation. So, yes, why not?